# Linux Reference for C++?

Tags: c++, linux, reference, include

I want to know if there is any site like cpluplus.com which explains all the headers files and its available features, but for Linux ? Like for example explaining the sys/*, net/*, dns/* includes ?

I came up with this question because I was searching for a sys/reboot.h reference.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your general question, but to your specific one: http://linux.die.net/man/2/reboot. Mostly for linux commands it helps to google for "linux man <command>"

Answer (score 7):

man pages are the usual references for C functions from headers. Sometimes you have to do `man 2` or `man 3` to get the C function rather than the shell command. You might also have to install an extra package for get these manpages.

e.g.

```
man 2 reboot
```

Comment: There's also the `apropos` command, which helps to track down commands by text in the manpages.

Answer (score 0):

Start a bash shell prompt, type 'a' 'Tab'. This lists all the commands that start with 'a'. If any command catches your attention, look at its associated man file. After the 'a' commands, repeat for 'b', etc. This, at least, is a systematic way of perusing the facilities available in your bin path.